# Transforming a trigonometric expression into exponential notation

Tags: output-formatting

I have a table as

```
{0, 1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] - Cos[(5 t)/4] + 
I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] - Sin[(5 t)/4])), 
1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] - Cos[(5 t)/4] + 
 I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] - Sin[(5 t)/4])), 0, 
1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] - Cos[(5 t)/4] + 
 I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] - Sin[(5 t)/4])), 0, 0, 0, 
1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] + 3 Cos[(5 t)/4] + 
I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] + 3 Sin[(5 t)/4]))}
```

The desire shape of this table will be as bellow, (of course, I created that manually)

[image]

Comment: Look up `TrigToExp[]`.

Comment: In this very speicifc case, you can do `TrigToExp[4 #]/4 & /@` your data. But how to make that constant multiplication term move automatically?

Comment: @kirma, I could not understand your question, but your code was very useful, even to factorize the multiplication factor (1/4) of all terms.

Comment: @kirma, that's where `FactorTerms[]` ought to be useful.

Comment: So to put my and @Guesswhoitis. 's answers together, you want to first apply `TrigToExp` on your data, then `FactorTerms` (both of these thread over lists automatically).

Comment: @kirma, besides so thanks of your comment, can you tell me what is the interpretation of [4 #] in the expression of ......TrigToExp[4 #]?

Comment: @Ackaran `#` is the first argument (`Slot`) of a pure function (`Function`), when defined with the `&` notation. This notation is very useful when combined with `Map` (shorthand `/@` - it applies the function to every item on the list separately) and some other typical tools of the trade. Please have a look at "pure functions" in the Mathematica documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collecting together the advice given in comments to the question by kirma and Guesswhoitis, the answer is

```
expr = 
  {0, 1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] - Cos[(5 t)/4] + I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] - Sin[(5 t)/4])), 
   1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] - Cos[(5 t)/4] + I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] - Sin[(5 t)/4])), 0, 
   1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] - Cos[(5 t)/4] + I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] - Sin[(5 t)/4])), 0, 0, 0, 
   1/4 (Cos[(3 t)/4] + 3 Cos[(5 t)/4] + I (-Sin[(3 t)/4] + 3 Sin[(5 t)/4]))};

FactorTerms[TrigToExp[expr]]
```

[image: result]